# Get role of other side in a bi-directional mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to dynamically get both roles of a many-to-many mapping. My setup is something like this (simplified):

```
class Item {
  String name;
  Set<Group> groups;
}

class Group {
  String name;
  Set<Item> items;
}
```

And this is mapped using many-to-many using XML, with Group.items as the owning side, and imagine I have several similar classes like this.

What I want is for every class, list up the owning role, and the inverse role using the metadata API, is this possible?

What I have done so far is:

- Fetched the PersistentClass of the class I'm looking at
- Fetched properties using PersistentClass.getPropertyClosureIterator()
- Iterate over all properties, and get check for type.isCollectionType()
- For every collection, I can cast to CollectionType and get the role of current collection

Now this gets my all the roles, but I don't know the connection between them.. I can find the join table etc, but not the actual role of the opposite side.

Any suggestions on how to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant, but found this solution to work good enough in my situation.

```
protected void updateJoinTables()
{
    if ( !roleToRole.isEmpty() )
    {
        return;
    }

    Map<String, List<String>> joinTableToRoles = new HashMap<>();

    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = getLocalSessionFactoryBean();
    SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactoryImplementor = (SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory;
    Iterator iterator = sessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration().getCollectionMappings();

    while ( iterator.hasNext() )
    {
        Collection collection = (Collection) iterator.next();
        CollectionPersister persister = sessionFactoryImplementor.getCollectionPersister( collection.getRole() );

        if ( persister.isManyToMany() && collection.getType().isAssociationType() )
        {
            AssociationType associationType = (AssociationType) collection.getType();
            Joinable associatedJoinable = associationType.getAssociatedJoinable( sessionFactoryImplementor );

            if ( !joinTableToRoles.containsKey( associatedJoinable.getTableName() ) )
            {
                joinTableToRoles.put( associatedJoinable.getTableName(), new ArrayList<String>() );
            }

            joinTableToRoles.get( associatedJoinable.getTableName() ).add( collection.getRole() );
        }
    }

    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> entryIterator = joinTableToRoles.entrySet().iterator();

    while ( entryIterator.hasNext() )
    {
        Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry = entryIterator.next();

        if ( entry.getValue().size() < 2 )
        {
            entryIterator.remove();
        }
    }

    for ( Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : joinTableToRoles.entrySet() )
    {
        roleToRole.put( entry.getValue().get( 0 ), entry.getValue().get( 1 ) );
        roleToRole.put( entry.getValue().get( 1 ), entry.getValue().get( 0 ) );
    }
}
```